# CHTML images size fit to div

Tags: html, css, yii

i wanna view an image in the size based on div that contains the image. i use yii framework.

i have a css code like this

```
    #ukuran1{
    margin: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    }
```

and a layout code like this

```
    <div id="ukuran1"><?php echo $this->ukuran1 ?></div>
```

and the view code like this

```
    $this->ukuran1 = CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/Desert.jpg');
```

the image shows, but in the actual size of the image. i want the image to sized as the div.
what shoul i do?

thanks guys..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this rule in your CSS:

```
 #ukuran1 img {
  width:100% !important;
  height:100% !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! this is really helpful..sorry can't rate your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
#ukuran1 {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    line-height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}

#ukuran1 img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

Try This